# How to achieve the function of ansible in lineinfile in chef

Tags: chef, ansible

I download a cookbook from https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/lineinfile,
But I found that this cookbook did not achieve the effect of up to date when chef-client was running.
What method can be achieved when the two amendment is able to up to date？

Comment: Show your code, please.

Answer (score -1):

Without knowing the specifics, the `line` cookbook is probably the closest, but we generally recommend avoiding this style as it leads to very brittle code.